# Reset after Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hidden

I am using a bit of jquery to expand a div when another is clicked:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".flip").click(function() {
            $(".module").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="flip"></div>
        <div class="module"></div>
```

And it has a lot of text in the module div.
This is my css:

```
 .module {
    width:374px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}
    .flip {
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    background-image:url(menu.gif);
    cursor:pointer;

}
```

My site is responsive, so when the browser window is resized the above css is displayed when the screen is less than 800px. So when testing, I click on my button which makes my module expand not a problem, and when I click the button again, the module collapses and hides it's content, so that's all good. However, when I resize my window back to say 1000px, and I had hidden the module content when my screen was smaller, the content is still hidden when the browser window is back to 1000px and I've hidden the button for the larger screens because it's not necessary.
So is there any way to reset the effects of the jquery when the browser window is resized to a size larger than 800px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if($(window).width() > 800) {
  location.reload();
 }
});
```

Use this script to check window size and reload

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) a library that add media query callbacks to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.resize()` which is used as resize event handler and then check whether the width hit the dimension.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 800) {
        $(".module").show();
    }
    else{
        $(".module").hide();
    }
});
```